# android emulator hardware acceleration on i5-2500K

Tags: linux, android

I just wanted to know if anyone have managed to start the android emulator with the "Use Host GPU" option checked on the i5-2500K buildin gpu using linux.

Each time i start it with "Use Host GPU" i just get the error "eglMakeCurrent failed" so do  need to install new drivers, or a new graphics card :}

I do have basic opengl support on linux, because my 3d opengl screensaver run fine.

Using Fedora 18